# Why does a GAE entity name have to be unique regardless of hierarchy?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am on Google App Engine, using Objectify. Consider the following simplified setup:

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup
{
    @Id
    private String identifier;
}

@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Parent
    Ref<UserGroup> usergroup;
}
```

Now what I assumed is that if I have two usergroups (let's call them A and B), I could have up to three User entities with a username of "admin": One with usergroup A as parent, one with usergroup B as parent, and one with no usergroup as parent.

However, that is not the case. If I create admin in group A, then admin with no group, then admin in group B, there is only one: The one in B, which overwrote the two others.

This, to me, seems inconsistent. I would not be able to find the one in B without specifying B as the parent entity, and just giving "admin" as name, because that would mean looking him up in the root. But if I create one with that name anywhere, it overwrites a user with the same name, regardless of his location in the object hierarchy.

My question is: Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made some sort of mistake in your test. {UserGroupA, "admin"} and {UserGroupB, "admin"} are indeed separate entities with separate keys.

Comment: How about that. You're right actually. A reduced testcase proves it. So, finding where my code is messing up, then. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a "User" entity using a key name as an ID, there will only be one unique "User" in the datastore with that ID : if you write twice a user with the same Key name in the datastore, the first write will be an "insert" and the second will be considered an "update".
In your use case maybe you should use an auto generated Key object for the ID, and have another field named "role" or something to put your "admin" value.